# Unable to plot Double Bar, Bar plot using pyplot for ndarray

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I have got these 2 `{ndarray}` which has 3 values of Positive, Negative and Neutral score.

```
>>>y1
array([82, 80, 63])
>>>y2
array([122,  73,  30])
```

For same I need `y1[0]` and `y2[0]` to be plotted together as they are corresponding as positive values, same goes with other 2 values from each array.

I tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def biplt(groundTruth, predictedValues, plt_name='<name>'):
        gt = groundTruth
        pr = predictedValues
        x = np.arange(2)

        y1, y2 = gt.values, pr.values
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1)

        width = 0.20
        plt.title('%s\n Accuracy Score' % plt_name)
        plt.xlabel('Parameters')
        plt.ylabel('Score')
        axes.bar(x, y1, width, label="Algorithm 1")
        axes.bar(x + width, y2, width, color=list(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])[2]['color'], label="Algorithm 2")
        axes.set_xticks(x + width)
        axes.set_xticklabels(['Positive', 'Negative'])
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
```

Which has resulted into `ValueError`, check below:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

I'm unable to diagnose with possible shape is of problem

I'm expecting a similar o/p:
[image: 2Bars for each criteria]

Comment: can you provide a mockup / drawing of what the resulting plot should look like? It is not obvious to me from your question.

Comment: @DizietAsahi yes, please check the changes in Question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`np.arange(2)` gives `array([0, 1])`, so only two values. If you try to plot three values (in `y1` or `y2`) against this, that won't work and it will throw the ValueError (telling you exactly this):

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Try using `np.arange(3)`.

Answer (score 7):

The Exception comes from the fact that you are trying to plot 3 `y` values against 2 x-values (see the [documentation on `np.arange()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)).

Here is a modified code that produces the desired output:

```
y1 = np.array([82, 80, 63])
y2 = np.array([122,  73,  30])

x = np.arange(len(y1))
width = 0.20

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1)
plt.title('Accuracy Score')
plt.xlabel('Parameters')
plt.ylabel('Score')
axes.bar(x, y1, width=-1.*width, align='edge', label="Algorithm 1")
axes.bar(x, y2, width=width, align='edge', color=list(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])[2]['color'], label="Algorithm 2")
axes.set_xticks(x)
axes.set_xticklabels(['Positive', 'Negative', 'Neutral'])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]